# Reading site contents using rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am able to read the Site Contents. But the redirecting link is not working. To get the hyperlink what can I do in my code.

Below is my code:

```
<script src=""></script>  
<div id="outputInfo"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        jQuery.ajax({  
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/AppTiles,Thumbnail",  
            method: "GET",  
            headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
            },  
            success: function(data) {  
                var appTiles = data.d.results;  
                console.log(appTiles);  
                var tempValue = "<h2>Site Contents</h2><br/>";  
                appTiles.forEach(function(app) {  
                    tempValue += app.Title + " <br/>";  
                });  
                $("#outputInfo").html(tempValue);  
            },


        error: function(data) {  
            console.log(data);  
        }  
    });  
})
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code to fetch the URL too:

```
<script src=""></script>  
<div id="outputInfo"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        jQuery.ajax({  
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/AppTiles",  
            method: "GET",  
            headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
            },  
            success: function(data) {  
                var appTiles = data.d.results;  
                console.log(appTiles);  
                var tempValue = "<h2>Site Contents</h2><br/>";  
                appTiles.forEach(function(app) {  
                    tempValue += app.Title + ":- " + _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + app.Target + " <br/>";  
                });  
                $("#outputInfo").html(tempValue);  
            },


        error: function(data) {  
            console.log(data);  
        }  
    });  
})
```

Comment: I achieved through:   appTiles.forEach(function(app) {
                    var url=app.Target;  
                    tempValue +="<a href='" + url + "'>"+ app.Title + "</a>"  + "<br />";

                });

Comment: Yes, you can set the URL using "app.Target" as your requirement. In the above, I have mentioned the URL besides each app title. 
Please accept it as answer.